# Getting error while exporting a song from iPod

Tags: iphone, xcode, avfoundation, ipod

I have written the code to export a song from iPod to my app. When I try to export a song from iPod, I am getting following error message.

```
AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x13b690 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x13b690 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: one person posted the same issue in following url;
http://openradar.appspot.com/8207641.

Comment: I have tested with some sample ".m4a" files. It is working good. I want to export MP3 files. Please help me to do this.

Comment: hey did u get any solution to export mp3 files

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to mp3 requires two steps: exporting to mov and extracting audio data from mov file to mp3. This library does the export: https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport
(I'm not an author, we are using it in our project).

Answer (score 0):

There might be already another file present at that location with the same name. Delete the old file and this will work.